# Ionic - Xcode Build Failed GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run an old Ionic (Cordova) project on iOS after successfully built for Android & Web.

- **"ionic info" command output:**

```
[ERROR] Error loading @ionic/v1-toolkit package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/v1-toolkit/package'
        
        Require stack:
        - /Users/jeffdavid/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/project/index.js
        - /Users/jeffdavid/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/index.js
        - /Users/jeffdavid/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/index.js
        - /Users/jeffdavid/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
[WARN] Bad integration name: gulp

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI         : 5.4.16 (/Users/jeffdavid/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.2
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : not installed

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (19 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.7.2

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.12.2
   NodeJS     : v18.16.0 (/Users/jeffdavid/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node)
   npm        : 9.7.1
   OS         : macOS Unknown
   Xcode      : Xcode 14.3.1 Build version 14E300c
```

- **"package.json" File Content**

```
{
  "name": "*",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "*",
  "scripts": {
    "ionic_run_world": "node build_scripts/build_world.js && ionic cordova run android",
    "ionic_build_world": "node build_scripts/build_world.js && ionic cordova build android --release --prod",
    "ionic_build_china": "node build_scripts/build_china.js && ionic cordova build android --release --prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/core": "5.0.5",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "^4.19.0",
    "cordova": "^8.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-custom-config": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": "^4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-fullscreen": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-insomnia": "^4.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.5",
    "gulp-bump": "^2.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "jsc-android": "^245459.0.0",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "localforage-cordovasqlitedriver": "^1.7.0",
    "nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.0.5",
    "@ionic/v1-toolkit": "1.0.17",
    "@moodlehq/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0-moodle.3",
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "bower": "^1.8.2",
    "cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "git+https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "git+https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git",
    "cordova-uglify": "^0.2.8",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^7.1.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-concat-json": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-cordova-bump": "^1.3.2",
    "gulp-cordova-config-xml": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-html-src": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-jsoncombine": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-jsonminify": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-preprocess": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-rev-append": "^0.1.8",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-useref": "^3.1.4",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "ionic-minify": "^2.0.10",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0",
    "yargs": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git",
      "id": "cordova-plugin-app-version"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-file",
    "cordova-plugin-compat",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics",
    "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview",
    "cordova-plugin-fullscreen",
    "nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio",
    "cordova-custom-config"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "android"
    },
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-custom-config": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "18.0.2"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-fullscreen": {},
      "nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "*",
        "ANDROID_SCHEME": " ",
        "ANDROID_HOST": " ",
        "ANDROID_PATHPREFIX": "/"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-insomnia": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROIDX_VERSION": "1.0.0",
        "ANDROIDX_APPCOMPAT_VERSION": "1.3.1"
      },
      "@moodlehq/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

- **"ionic.config.json" File Content**

```
{
  "name": "**",
  "integrations": {
    "gulp": {},
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "browsers": [
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "browser": "crosswalk",
      "version": "14.42.334.0"
    }
  ],
  "watch": {
    "sass": [
      "scss/**/*.scss"
    ],
    "html": [
      "www/**/*.html"
    ],
    "livereload": [
      "www/**/*.html",
      "www/**/*.js",
      "www/**/*.css"
    ]
  },
  "type": "ionic1",
  "watchPatterns": [
    "scss/**/*",
    "www/**/*",
    "!www/lib/**/*",
    "!www/**/*.map"
  ]
}
```

**What I Tried & Conclusions:**

1. Tried to use different Intel & M2 Chip MacBook Pros and got the same errors, so hardware may not cause the problem.
2. 'npm install' only works while switching to `node v10.24.1 (npm v6.14.12)` using NVM, because otherwise there is an upstream dependency conflict with "rxjs" from "@ionic/native"

After the 'npm install' I switched to Node.js v16.16 and performed ``cordova platform add ios``, opened the .xcworkspace file, tried to run on an iOS simulator and got the following error during the "Build Failed" phase:

```
/Users/jeffdavid/Developer/GitLab//platforms/ios/*  /Plugins/cordova-plugin-google-analytics/UniversalAnalyticsPlugin.h:6:9
'GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h' file not found
```

**EDIT:**

Running `sudo gem install cocoapods` may fixed the issue, still trying to resolve.